# Xamarin.Forms Background Thread

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, synchronization, background-thread

I'm trying to get a really simple application running listing google Task.
I have a SQLite local db I'd like to sync / try syncing at regular interval with Google's server.

I was thinking of simply running a simple background thread so it'd work easily on all devices.

Problem comes down creating that background thread in a PCL project (Xamarin.Forms)
I can't seem to find a proper way of making one.

Currently I just have a second thread running as such:

```
    private bool Sync() { //Does stuffs }

    private void SynchronizeData()
    {
        // Repeats sync process every 35s
        Device.StartTimer (new TimeSpan (0, 0, 35), Sync);
    }

    // Is called pretty much when app starts.
    private void StartSynchronizationThread()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(SynchronizeData, 
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

While it should anyway not be much of a problem considering operation count is really low (worst case for testing purpose it'd be less than a sec blocking) i experience a massive freeze of my application around when thread should be ran first. (Timer expiring for the first time)
The freeze last for a good minute...

Once it hapenned, i can stay on the app mostly forever without a single issue. I noticed the following appears quite later though:

> [art]
>   Thread[2,tid=2532,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xee170800,peer=0x12c00080,"Signal
>   Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3 [art] Wrote stack traces to
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt' [art] Wrote stack traces to
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt' [art]
>   Thread[2,tid=2532,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xee170800,peer=0x12c00080,"Signal
>   Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3 [art] Wrote stack traces to
>   '/data/anr/traces.txt'

Traces aren't really giving me much more informations though...
But it probably have to do with it.

As anyone a hint regarding this matter ? Package, code example or anything ?
Hopefully I missed out on something big e;

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working like a charm on an actual device, the issue was linked to the emulator. (Haven't found a fix for it though)

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin forms you have to go native for a proper background task, as described here:
[Backgrounding with Xamarin Forms](http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/)

To go native you need to use the [Xamarin MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/) to send messages back and forth to an appropriate background task (depending on what you're trying to achieve). For example, defining a service in Android:

```
[Service]
class YourService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        // Do your thang!
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunatly I had been done a while before you answered and couldn't give a try to your solution but  I'll make sure to try it out if the occassion ever presents itself :P

Hopefully this can lead other people on the right way though ;D