# Xamarin Forms App as TCP Server

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tcpserver

I have a cross-platform Xamarin.Forms app (iOS and Android) which provides a specific service. This service code is in PCL part of the project and I want to use it on web client as well using my app as server. Is there a way to implement TCP server in the app which listens to incoming connections and provides with the service.

Do I have to use platform specific background services to run TCPListener? The server should only be running when the app is in foreground.

I have tried to look for answers over forums and got bits and pieces. 
All I need right now is right direction to go to:

- [Server Client Application with .NET and Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823404/server-client-application-with-net-and-xamarin)
- [Xamarin.Forms Background Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566661/xamarin-forms-background-thread)
- [Sockets PCL Plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/rda.socketsforpcl)

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I understand that I have to write platform specific implementation to use background services/tasks. Similarly System.Net.Sockets is only supported in platform specific projects. However can I write PCL implementation using background thread and Sockets PCL plugins I mentioned in question? I am not very experienced in multithreading, could you please provide a sample example :)

Comment: And how do I get to know server IP (phone's IP) on client side (web application). Web page would however be running in same app through a web-view.